# Hide a href element based on a class using plain JavaScript not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Using plain JavaScript I'm attempting to hide a href element based on the class name. I've got it working in Firefox, however the element still shows up in Chrome. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction! I've done a lot of Googling and I think I've just confused myself further :(

This is what I'm trying to hide on the page. I don't have access to change it directly in the code and can only use pure JavaScript to make a change to the system.

```
<a href="" title="Create Form" class="scope-filter-create-board js-create-board">Create Form</a>
```

This is the code I've tried:

Using an array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

window.onload = function () {

var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("js-create-board"); //divsToHide is an array

    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        
    }
}

});
```

Specifying it exactly without the array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

window.onload = function () {

document.getElementsByClassName('js-create-board')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
});
```

And I've also tried just this - again works in FF but not Chrome?

```
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementsByClassName('js-create-board')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

}

Comment: Hiding/showing is not the role of javascript, but CSS. I would define a class for the basic element, and a second class only for hiding it, then give/remove this second class with javascript

Comment: You need to decide what you gonna use, DOMContentLoaded or onload. Your loop by class name should work. (in case you have more of those elements and/or one) And yeah, just use CSS for this as suggested....

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="" title="Create Form" class="scope-filter-create-board js-create-board">Create Form</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const link =  document.querySelector('.scope-filter-create-board.js-create-board')
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for both `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload`! I would say the more correct event is `window.onload`. The following should work in any modern browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (async () => {
    
    // Wait for window to load
    await new Promise(r => window.addEventListener('load', r));
    
    // Reference your link element and set its display to 'none' (hiding it entirely)
    document.querySelector('a.js-create-board').style.display = 'none';
    
  })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove `a` tag by one JavaScript line

```
document.getElementsByClassName("scope-filter-create-board")[0].outerHTML = ""
```